# error when using g++: 'malloc' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, namespaces, g++, malloc

I am practicing g++ to compile my code yet the error "malloc was not declared in this scope" keeps emerging at the beginning. The pieces of my code related to this error looks like:

```
/*------Basic.h--------*/
using namespace std;

/*------A.h------------*/
class A{
 private:
  double* _data;
 public:
 A(int N);
}

/*------A.cpp----------*/
A::A(int N){
  _data=(double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
}
```

This problem never emerges when I use Microsoft Virtual Stdio. I therefore tried to add a line

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

to Basic.h, and the error disappears. Now I am wondering why this kind of thing happens. Hasn't "namespace std" already include stdlib.h? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Closely related (almost a duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278864/what-is-the-difference-between-header-file-and-namespace

Comment: Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115556/c-using-namespace-and-include. I am going to vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: Avoid putting using directives in headers.

Comment: I was keeping searching questions about "malloc" instead of "namespace std "so I didn't find any closely related question.  Thanks for your links, jogojapan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespaces and include files are two totally different things. You need to

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

or, equivalently,

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

in order to get access to the declarations in that header file.

Your *using-declaration*

```
using namespace std;
```

on the other hand, means that you can use identifiers that are part of the namespace `std`, i.e. that were declared inside

```
namespace std {
  /*...*/
}
```

**without prepending** `std::` each time.

**For example,** if you `include <string>`, you can use the data type `std::string`, but if you *also* add `using namespace std;`, you can use that data type simply as `string`.

Note, however, that `malloc` is not defined inside any namespace, so in order to use that, you need only to include `stdlib.h`.

**Note** For the difference between `stdlib.h` and `cstdlib`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301586/what-is-the-difference-between-using-includefilename-and-includefilename-h).

Answer (score 2):

`malloc()` is defined in `<cstdlib>` so you must include it at the top of your file.

`using namespace std;` just tells the compile that you're using that particular namespace, and has nothing to with including any library methods.

In any case, you really should be using `new` rather than `malloc` for dynamic allocation when using C++.

Comment: stdlib.h is a perfectly acceptable alternative to cstdlib.  Which to use is mostly a style thing, and has more to do with whether you're using more C or C++ APIs in your code.  Likewise blanket pronouncements about new vs malloc aren't really helpful.  C++ is far too broad a language for that kind of pedantry.

Comment: @AndyRoss: `malloc` allocates raw memory, `new` allocates memory *and correctly constructs objects*. C++ needs the differentiation necessarily. Most of the time, people want a new object, not raw memory.

Comment: Why in Microsoft Vitual Stdio there is nothing wrong? Does VC set cstdlib as default? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`using namespace std;` tells the compiler, *I'm "using" the `std` namespace, so **pretend like I'm in the `std` namespace for lookups** and don't ask me to say `std::` every time*.

The trouble is, there is *nothing in* the `std` namespace (yet)!

You need to `#include` the header for `malloc` to be declared.

And even then, it's global -- not in `std`.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'new' for memory allocation.
'using namespace std' has nothing to do with stdlib.h
IF you still want to use malloc() add this on the top

```
#include<cstdlib>
```

Good luck!